# I had asked a question on meta.stackexchange approx 3 months ago and it does not show up anywhere

Tags: support, mso-mse-split

I can not see the question in any disposition in my meta.stackexchange questions.  Any ideas?

Comment: A name or something would be useful when posting a question like this next time.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I found it - got moved to meta.stack**overflow**.com  Confusing to have two sites.

Comment: There are **a lot** more than 2 meta sites.  There is a meta site for every site in the network.

Comment: There is a major difference between the meta's. The site meta's (like http://meta.stackoverflow.com) are only about the main site (in this case SO). This meta (http://meta.stackexchange.com) is about the entire network.